# Remove Ubuntu from dual boot and reinstall windows 10 on two drives laptop

Tags: windows, ubuntu, reset

I have a laptop with 2 drives and windows 10 on the first drive and Ubuntu 18.04 on the second. I want to delete Ubuntu from the second drive and restore factory settings and reinstall windows 10. Reset my PC will remove Ubuntu or only the first drive?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/1338920/dual-booting-windows-and-ubuntu-factory-reset-windows-remove-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Reset my PC will only apply to the Windows disk.

To reuse the second disk in Windows, you will need to reformat it as NTFS.